# Finding the equation of an ellipse tangent to two lines

Tags: calculus, geometry

Find the equation of the ellipse tangent to the two lines
$$x-4y=10$$ and $$x+y=5$$

I know that the equation of ellipse in general is 
$$ \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$$

but how can continue? I substituted for   $x $ from the equations of the two lines in the equation of ellipse but it still difficult to continue!

is it true to take $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$ ??

Comment: There are certainly at least 4 ellipses tangent to those lines. I'm not sure there aren't infinitely many. Is this all you're given?

Comment: There is an infinite number of circles tangent to a pair of lines, let alone ellipses, so more information is needed for anything but the most general (and not very useful) solution. You appear to be assuming that the ellipse is aligned with the coordinate axes, but that doesn’t narrow it down much. Perhaps, as you suspect, this ellipse is meant to be centered at the origin?

Comment: I think yes , we will work in ellipse in standard form ,which the origin is the center of the ellipse .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

The equation of an ellipse is
$$ax^2+by^2=1 \tag1$$

the intersection with a tangent is a double point which means that the discriminant $\delta $ is zero.

the first line gives $x=4y+10$ what we plug in $(1) $ to get

$$(16a+b)y^2+80ay+100a=1$$

$\delta=0$ gives a first equation satisfied by $a $ and $b $.

the other tangent gives the second equation .

Comment: "the intersection with a tangent is a double point which means that the discriminant δδ is zero." what this mean ! I didn't understand it!

Comment: If $b^2-4ac=0$ then the equation $ay^2+by+c=0$ has a double root.

Comment: but I think you wrote the equation of the ellipse wrong $$ax^2+by^2=ab$$

Comment: because the general form of ellipse equation is $$ \frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b}=1$$

Comment: It's okey , there is no wrong in your equation , it just the difference in the shape ! thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This might be beyond what you’ve studied, but one way to solve this problem is to move to projective geometry and use the *dual ellipse*, which consists of all of the lines tangent to the ellipse.

For the ellipse in standard position ${x^2\over a^2}+{y^2\over b^2}=1$, its projective equation can be expressed in matrix form as $\mathbf x^TQ\mathbf x=0$, where $$Q=\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{a^2}&0&0\\0&\frac1{b^2}&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Its dual is expressed similarly as $\mathscr lQ^{-1}\mathscr l^T=0$, where the components of $\mathscr l=(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$ are the coefficients of the equation $\lambda x+\mu y+\nu=0$ of the line represented by $\mathscr l$. (In practice, it’s often more convenient to use the *adjugate* $\det(Q)Q^{-1}$ instead of $Q^{-1}$ for the dual.) Every $\mathscr l$ that satisfies this dual equation is tangent to the ellipse.

In this case, $Q^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(a^2,b^2,-1)$ and plugging in the two given lines results in the equations $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-4&-10\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a^2&0&0\\0&b^2&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-4\\-10\end{bmatrix}=a^2+16b^2-100=0 \\
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a^2&0&0\\0&b^2&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\-5\end{bmatrix}=a^2+b^2-25=0.$$ Solve these equations for $a$ and $b$ and you have your ellipse.